# JAVA LOOP FOR NEWTON RAPHSONS METHOD

Tags: java

I know the code below is a bit rough , i just need to get it to work before i clean it up. I'm working on newton raphson's methood that repeats as long as a condition is through. here's what i've got so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.System.in;

public class NewtonRaphson {

public static float intervalfunctions(float b){
      return ((b*b*b)-3*b+1);
}
public static float differentiatedfunctions(float b) {
     return (3*(b*b)-3);
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(in);
out.println("PROGRAMME TO SOLVE NEWTON'S SCHEME");
    float  E, Z, F, D, G,FF,fa,fb,b,fx,ffx,x1;
    float x[] = new float[10];
    out.println("Enter the accauracy required");
        E = myScanner.nextFloat();
    out.println("Enter the first Interval");
        D = myScanner.nextFloat();
    out.println("Enter the final interval");
        G = myScanner.nextFloat();
        fa = intervalfunctions(D);
        fb = intervalfunctions(G);
    if ((fa * fb)<0) {
        out.println("The Solution exists between the given interval");
        x[0] = (D+G)/2;
        fx = intervalfunctions(x[0]);
        ffx = differentiatedfunctions(x[0]);

    x[1] = x[0] - (fx/ffx);
        out.println("x[1] is ");
        out.print(x[1]);

}
```

now i need a way to `loop x` and differentiated functions for the next values where `x0` changes to `x1` and `x1` to `x2` on and on to an error tolerance of `10^-2`. i know i'll definitely need a `while loop` and maybe a `for loop` , but i need a way to loop through my `x array` .. i couldnt do this for `(x[1++])` . i'll also need a way to loop my methods for each new value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I'm following what you are trying to calculate, but if I understood your explanation, you need a loop similar to this :

```
x[0] = (D+G)/2;
fx = intervalfunctions(x[0]);
ffx = differentiatedfunctions(x[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    x[i] = x[i-1] - (fx/ffx);
    fx = intervalfunctions(x[i]);
    ffx = differentiatedfunctions(x[i]);
}
```